# What is the page variable in Capybara tests?

Tags: ruby, cucumber, capybara

When using Capybara, what is the difference between calling `page.find('#name')` and `find('#name')`.

Is it that same thing, as this answer states [What's the meaning of page and page.body in Capybara](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30800699/whats-the-meaning-of-page-and-page-body-in-capybara)

I am just looking for more of an explanation and when I would need to use `page` outside of asserts.

Comment: I've also asked the same question some time ago [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29286772/difference-between-using-page-find-and-find)  ...  I've given up using the page variable as my specs look a lot cleaner now.  I still have no idea what the difference is in terms of what it is really used for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it is described in source code:

```
# Shortcut to accessing the current session.
# @return [Capybara::Session] The current session object

def page
  Capybara.current_session
end
```

When you do `find('#name')` current session's `find` method is called. So there is no difference between calling `page.find('#name')` and `find('#name')`.   
I guess this shortcut was created just to keep asserts code intuitive and understandable:

```
expect(page).to have_css(#name)
```

looks better than

```
expect(Capybara.current_session).to have_css(#name)
```